# Global std::string causing crash on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, std

I've submitted this as a bug to Apple, but just for confirmation, here is the test code:

```
#include <string>

std::string home_directory;

std::string BuildPath(const std::string directory, const std::string path)
{
  if(home_directory.compare(directory) == 0)
    printf("In home directory\n");

  return directory + "/" + path;
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
  home_directory = "home";
  printf("Home: '%s'\n", home_directory.c_str());
  printf("BuildPath: '%s'\n", BuildPath("base", "path").c_str());
}
```

When built with the latest XCode 5.1, iOS SDK 7.1 and LLVM 5.1, using libstdc++ for the C++ standard library, this crashes somewhere in the std::string implementation on the return line from the BuildPath function when run on an iOS 5.1 device.

The output is

```
Home: 'home'
CrashTest(1242) malloc: *** error for object 0x2fe2ac80: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

The stack crawl:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34fb8848 __kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36eae2ae abort + 110
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x36e6937a free + 374
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x3481a93a operator delete(void*) + 6
4   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34806138 std::string::_Rep::_M_dispose(std::allocator<char> const&) + 68
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34806c04 std::string::reserve(unsigned long) + 156
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x34806daa std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) + 70
7   CrashTest                       0x00094a30 BuildPath(std::string, std::string) (basic_string.h:2121)
8   CrashTest                       0x00094bda main (main.cpp:25)
9   CrashTest                       0x0009499c start + 32
```

With optimisation levels of -O1 or less, or using libc++ as the standard library, it works as expected. It also works as expected on iOS 6 or 7. When built with the previous release of XCode (5.0.2, iOS SDK 7.0 and LLVM 5.0) it works fine regardless of optimisation settings.

Commenting out the comparison with the global string also avoids the crash.

Can anyone see any issues with my code? If not, any theories for the cause of the crash? Perhaps a new LLVM optimisation that triggers a bug in the libstdc++ runtime in iOS 5.1?

Another option I can think of is that the optimizer is generating invalid code. That would be much more of a worry.

Comment: Try replacing `std::string` with the `vstring` from the extensions directory.

Comment: This is a minimal test case from our larger cross-platform project. I don't want to replace std::string everywhere.

Comment: I can't see any technical problem with the code. It looks as if `home_directory` has not been initialized. But the C++11 standard requires in §3.6.2/4 that it be initialized either before first statement of `main` or, if after, then "before the first odr-use (3.2) of any function or variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable". Whichever is done, it will guarantee that it's initialized at the time that it's used here. There is a fine point here about the time *during* the first statement of `main`. g++ weird behavior is often tied to fine points, the "perverse compiler" idea.

Comment: I did also try initialising ```home_directory``` when it was declared, exact same behaviour. The first printf in main shows that it does have the expected value (and a printf in BuildPath shows the same), but I suppose the object itself may have been improperly initialised leading to it appearing to work for assignment, but actually be trashing some other memory?

Comment: Looks like it's crashing in `free()`, probably while deleting the temporary object created in the `return` statement. This is definitely a bug, probably a library bug, there's nothing wrong with that code. I've been seeing a lot of these weird little C-related bugs since Xcode 5.0. I've been reporting them too -- hopefully they'll be fixed soon. Although the fact that this only happens in pre-iOS 6 won't help much. Apple doesn't have much motivation to fix that, given their high penetration for upgrades.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here with xcode 5.1/iOS 7.1 SDK on ios 5.1.1 that occurs when trying to concatenate a string that looks essentially the same as the your line of code 'directory + "/"' when built with optimisations. It tries to allocate ~800MB of memory when expanding the string and crashes the app.

Comment: Apple closed the bug with some standard message about not caring for bugs that only affect iOS 5, despite my protestations about wanting to confirm it wasn't a compiler/optimiser issue. Annoying.

Comment: We are having same bug here. Crash only iOS 5.1.1. If app was compiled in XCode 5.0 - ALL IS FINE. If in XCode 5.1 - we see crash. Optim level in XCOde 5.1 solving problem, but it's not good way. Anyone told about this bug in XCode 5.1 to Apple?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't run your test case under gdb and step thru it? You can't just blindly trust an optimized stack trace like that - some of the "call sites" will actually be return addresses rather than origins. Also, your actual code isn't passing `std::string` by value like that, is it? Does the code still crash if you replace the `return` with a local variable assignment followed by a return of the local variable? http://ideone.com/x7Ajch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple released a new GM seed for Xcode 5.1.1.  In the release notes they say they fixed a couple crashes:

> Fixed a compiled code crash on when targeting iOS 5.1.1. (16485980)!
>
> Fixed a compiled code crash when using ARC and C++. (16368824)

http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_5.1.1_gm_seed/release_notes_xcode_5.1.1_gm_seed.pdf

Comment: I didn't test against the GM seed, but Apple did later release XCode 5.1.1 (and associated command line tools) as an App Store update. Using that version fixes the crashes both with the small test case above and my larger app.